# Name an Armor Stand using the Standard Galactic Alphabet

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The Standard Galactic Alphabet is what appears in the Enchanting Table. Is there a way to give a name to an Armor Stand using these character.

I know there is a LingoJam Translator that give ASCII characters that look like the SGA, but that is not what I'm looking for. Can I use the same characters as the Enchanting Table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name an amorstand with a custom font by using the "font" parameter. You can also give yourself a nametag with the font you want.

Here are few exemples with commands:

```
/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName: '{"italic":false,"font":"minecraft:alt","text":"custom name"}'}
```

- This command spawn an armorstand with a custom name

```
/give @s minecraft:name_tag{display:{Name:'[{"text":"your text here","italic":false,"font":"alt"}]'}} 1
```

- This command give you a nametag with a custom name, you can rename an armor stand with it

```
/data merge entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,sort=nearest,limit=1] {CustomNameVisible:1}
```

- This make the armor stand name visible because it's not normally

Comment: These commands work. Thank you. This was a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

What the enchanting table uses is just a different font. The text in it is just a random arrangement of words listed [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting_Table#Standard_Galactic_Alphabet) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Enchanting_Table&oldid=1405691)).

So the way to write with it would be a resource pack that replaces the font or to use Unicode characters that look similar, which you have denied for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to name any entity using the Standard Galactic Alphabet. The closest you will get is to use the LingoJam translator characters. You can only name an entity with Unicode characters so you can not name an armor stand with Standard Galactic Alphabet characters. You could create a texture pack and change some of the Unicode characters to look like Standard Galactic Alphabet Characters. Here is some more information on that. https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_pack#Fonts